# detect lines on digital xray image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am looking to detect lines on an x-ray image using OpenCV. Please see the attached sample images.

I am aware of Hough transform. Is there any other reliable approach using OpenCV or any other C++ library ? I am also looking to somehow determine the confidence for each detected line, such as line[20] has confidence of 1 (maximum), line[30] has next best confidence of 0.95 and so on

Sample Image

[image]

Output Image (potential lines are circled)

[image]

Any help will be really appreciated in this regard

Comment: Kind of hard to say without seeing what you are talking about...

Comment: I have added more details